# OutputStream.write(byte[] bytes) give NetworkOnMainThread Exception But i am not using this method On Main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, networking, wifip2p

Code :

```
private class SendReceive extends Thread{
    private Socket socket;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;


    public SendReceive(Socket sock){
        this.socket=sock;
        try{
            inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
            outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
        int bytes;
        while(socket!=null){
            try{
                bytes=inputStream.read(buffer);
                if(bytes>0){
                    handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ,bytes,-1,buffer).sendToTarget();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes){
        try {
            outputStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

Inside this class

Inside write method

outputStream.write(bytes) causing NetworkOnMainThread Exception

I am using separate thread but why this is showing MainThreadException

Please tell me what i am missing here.
Thanks in advance

Edited//////////////////
I am calling write function inside here

```
  sendTextMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(getDataFromPreviousActivity!=null) {
                String mesg =getDataFromPreviousActivity;
                sendReceive.write(mesg.getBytes());
            }
        }
    });
```

Inside the onCreate function

Comment: show where you call `write`

Comment: The only thing in that code that will be run on a background thread is `run()`, and that only if you use `start()` to start the `Thread`. Just because `write()` is a method on a subclass of `Thread` does not mean that it will be run on a background thread.

Comment: `public void write()` You made it public. Make it private and dont call it from another class.